# Desktop PC no display at all

Tags: display, cpu, motherboard

I have a desktop PC that turns on but shows no display whatsoever.

I have tried everything I could find so if anyone could give any suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

I checked that the following items were installed properly: CPU, CPU fan, RAM, Power cables.  On the motherboard, I checked the CDROM and Hard drive.

I know the monitor and HDMI cable work as I tested them on another machine.

When I plug my keyboard directly into any USB port on the motherboard, the keyboard LED does not shine even when machine powered on with fans spinning.

Could it be that the CPU needs the motherboards chipset installed onto it?

Could it be that the motherboard is faulty like a soldering issue?

**Here are systems specs**

- motherboard: Asus prime A520m-E
- CPU - AMD Ryzen 7 5700G
- RAM - 2* ddr4 8gb (no branding)
- Power supply - Corsair CV650 ATX
- Case - Cit f3 Micro ATX
- Drive - 1TB Hard disk (windows installed on)
- CDROM

Situation (can read if you want):

- My cousins PC, was a pre-built gaming PC.
- We ordered the CPU (AMD Ryzen 7 5700G) of amazon.
- The previous motherboard (ASUS Prime A520m-E r2) was not compatible.
- My cousin brough a new PSU.
- My auntie asked me to fix it as they spent a lot of money.
- I managed to get the old PC working but now am not able to get the new components working.

I am going to try again tomorrow with fresh eyes. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

**UPDATE**: Thank you guys for help! I think I may have found the issue but am not sure. On this site:

https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/PRIME/PRIME-A520M-E/HelpDesk_CPU/

It says BIOS version that supports the AMD Ryzen 7 5700g processor is 1401.

Now this site:

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-check-if-you-have-latest-motherboard-bios-amd-ryzen-5000-cpus

Says the motherboard has 1202

So I just have to change the BIOS version and everything should work fine. But the motherboard doesn’t seem to have BIOS flash so I think will have to get into contact with AMD.

Comment: Could try to clear the CMOS. Also, do you get any beep codes? Another thing you could try is re seating the RAM/CPU.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I will give the CMOS a try tomorrow, I have not actual audio output so I do not know but will definitely try this tomorrow, thank you. I have reseated the cpu and ram but will do again if no luck with either of these. Appreciated :)

Comment: `Could it be that the CPU needs the motherboards chipset installed onto it?` .. I would say no as this makes no sense to me.  Pull and re-seat the ram but put only one ram module in until you get this working.  Try different ram slots if the mobo supports it (even if not optimal).  Swap ram modules to test each one. Pull and re-seat the CPU.  Pull and re-seat the motherboard cables.

Comment: Ok I will try all of this thank you. The mobo came with the chipset drivers cd so I thought to put cd in cdrom and perhaps it would install the necessary drivers automatically but it didn't.

Comment: Asus has a failsafe/button press update option on many systems that may not need a processor. Might be worth checking your manual for it

Comment: I could not find this but thank you for suggestion. I have just sent amd boot kit request so hopefully that will work